# issues with margin and flex in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to add a margin so the borders arent touching the edges of the screen. however, when i try to, my grid will wrap and start a new row instead of staying in the same spot. i have to keep my values responsive so i can't set my boxes to be a specific #.

I am using react native and here is a snippet of how the grid looks before margin+ after adding margin:

[image: NO margins]
[image: Added margin]

my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window'); 
const size = Math.min(width, height) / 3; 

const Grid = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.row}>

          <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>1</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>2</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>3</Text>
          </View>

        </View>



      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeArea: {
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    //margin: 10,
  },
  box: {
    width: size,
    height: size,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
});

export default Grid;
```

i added the following to my box styling:

```
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    borderWidth: 1
```

this fixed the boxes being pushed around but now my text is weirdly spaced at the top. if anyone could help me figure out how to fix this it'd be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: `const size = Math.min(width, height) / 3; ` - you didn't count margin here

Comment: @Konrad how do i count the margin inside there? (sorry if dumb question im rlly bad at coding)

Comment: Probably `const size = Math.min(width - 20, height) / 3; ` but I wouldn't suggest doing things like that

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using CSS for this, but Layout Props:   https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#marginhorizontal

Also important to note that in React Native, the `flex` value is a number instead of a string.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#flex

So your code would look something along these lines:

```
    <SafeAreaView flex={1}>
      <View flex={1} marginHorizontal="1em">
        <View style={styles.box}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.box}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.box}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

I don't have a React Native setup at the moment so I'm not able to test it, but [this page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props) in general should give you a lot of insight into how to style things in React native instead of Web.
There are many particularities.

Edit: Another thing that seems quite anti-pattern to me is having to calculate the screen width in order to apply margin. The solution I'm proposing eliminates that need, which will also make it faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
box: {
  flex: 1,
  aspectRatio: 1,
  borderWidth: 1
}
```

Comment: this makes my boxes extremely tiny :(

Comment: You have to set width of the parent to 100% I guess

Comment: thanks, this made the boxes fit!! but now my text isn't centered - i have   textAlign: 'center' for the styling but the text is appearing in the top side of the box